# Route guard doesn't work with 2 observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7, ionic4

I have written `route guard` as shown below. But on the `else` statement where this never return a result. But it has a result. And no errors also. 
`this.hotelSettingsService.get().pipe(map(res => {
          if (res) {`

It works if I remove this `from(this.localStorageService.get(LocalStorage.SCROLL_VIEW_HOLDER)).pipe(map(path` section.

I think I have done something fundamentally wrong. Any clue?

***Video about this behavior:*** [Video](https://youtu.be/QBDSqgT5YVk)

```
 canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {

    return from(this.localStorageService.get(LocalStorage.SCROLL_VIEW_HOLDER)).pipe(map(path => {
      if (path) {
        this.router.navigate(path);
        return true;
      } else {
        this.hotelSettingsService.get().pipe(map(res => {
          if (res) { // not come to here
            this.router.navigate([this.getLandingPage(environment.hotelName)]);
            return true;
          }
        }), catchError((err) => {
          return of(false);
        }));
      }
    }), catchError((err) => {
      return of(false);
    }));
  }
```

When I put a `return`:

[image]

This is working fine:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {

        return this.hotelSettingsService.get().pipe(map(res => {
              if (res) { 
                this.router.navigate([this.getLandingPage(environment.hotelName)]);
                return true;
              }
            }), catchError((err) => {
              return of(false);
            }));
          }
     }
```

Comment: what happens if you return of(true)?

Comment: Without the return, when you fall on the `else` no value will be returned inside the outer `map`

Comment: with the return, your IDE correctly explodes

Comment: @Jota.Toledo No idea about what you're telling? Can you put your suggestion with code?

Comment: @EhsanKiani No difference. You can see `This is working fine:` section. It is working fine with `return true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add `return` in front of `this.hotelService....` like you have added in your image. Then you need to flatten the result using `switchMap` instead of `map`:

```
 canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    // since we have (possibly) an inner observable, flatten the result
    return from(...).pipe(switchMap(path => {
      if (path) {
        this.router.navigate(path);
        // return observable of
        return of(true);
      } else {
        return this.hotelSettingsService.get().pipe(map(res => {
          if (res) {
            this.router.navigate([this.getLandingPage(environment.hotelName)]);
            return true;
          }
        }), catchError((err) => {
          return of(false);
        }));
      }
    }), catchError((err) => {
      return of(false);
    }));
  }
```